# How query data with azure stream analytics based on partition key

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I'm sending data to streaming as below format.

```
[
  {
    "body":{
        "indice":"NIFTY 50",
        "advances":"13"
    },
    "applicationProperties":{
        "id":3
    },
    "partitionKey":"pk788",
    "EventProcessedUtcTime":"2019-09-27T09:11:18.4997132Z",
    "PartitionId":1,
    "EventEnqueuedUtcTime":"2019-09-27T09:11:10.3310000Z"
  },
  {
    "body":{
        "symbol":"BAJFINANCE",
        "tradedQuantity":"16,00,866"
    },
    "applicationProperties":{
        "id":2
    },
    "partitionKey":"pk787",
    "EventProcessedUtcTime":"2019-09-27T09:11:18.4997132Z",
    "PartitionId":1,
    "EventEnqueuedUtcTime":"2019-09-27T09:11:10.3310000Z"
  }
]
```

Where I tried to query this data using the following query

```
Select * from NSEStockInput
where partitionKey = 'pk788'
```

I'm getting the error as below
 An unexpected error has occured. Please open a support ticket to investigate and provide the following client request id: undefined
How to resolve this

Comment: You should run the payload you're sending through a tool like this: https://jsonlint.com/ to ensure the json is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your sample is not a valid Json. Can you please try removing '[' next to second "body" property.

Comment: There actually seems to be a lot wrong with the JSON payload, can you revise this answer to call out the rest of the issues?

Answer (score 0):

By correcting JSON syntax errors, I got the message format:

```
[
    {
        "body":{
            "indice":"NIFTY 50",
            "advances":"13"
        },
        "applicationProperties":{
            "id":3
        },
        "partitionKey":"pk788",
        "EventProcessedUtcTime":"2019-09-27T09:11:18.4997132Z",
        "PartitionId":1,
        "EventEnqueuedUtcTime":"2019-09-27T09:11:10.3310000Z"
    },
    {
        "body":{
            "symbol":"BAJFINANCE",
            "tradedQuantity":"16,00,866"
        },
        "applicationProperties":{
            "id":2
        },
        "partitionKey":"pk787",
        "EventProcessedUtcTime":"2019-09-27T09:11:18.4997132Z",
        "PartitionId":1,
        "EventEnqueuedUtcTime":"2019-09-27T09:11:10.3310000Z"
    }
]
```

You can use the following query to extract the partitionKey:

```
with inputStream as (select input.* from input)


SELECT *
INTO Output
FROM inputStream
WHERE partitionKey = 'pk788'
```